# Duvida/Problema Com WebService em Android

Tags: android, web-service

O retorno no meu WebService está assim:

> "OlÃ¡!\n\n estou interessado em seus serviÃ§os. Meu nome Ã© Administrador B. Por favor, me contate pelo(s) telefone(s) (12) 3456-7891; (13) 21321-3213. Meu e-mail Ã© adm@adm. \n\n Atenciosamente, \n\nAdministrador B"

o correto seria assim:

> Olá! estou interessado em seu anúncio de trabalho cvbcvbaaa. Por favor, me contate pelo(s) telefone(s) (12) 3456-7891; (13) 21321-3213. Meu e-mail é adm@adm. Atenciosamente, Administrador B

Como eu poderia fazer para ficar correto??

Estou recebendo assim do WebService

```
private void makeJsonObjReq(){
        showProgressDialog();
        int id = ((AppController) this.getApplication()).getID();
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Const.URL_JSON_ARRAY_Notificacao + "/"+id,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hideProgressDialog();

                        int aJsonint = 0;
                        String aJsonString;

                        itens = new ArrayList<ItemListaNotificacao>();

                        // Recupera seu adapter

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonarray = response;
                            JSONObject jsonobj;

                            for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
                                jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                                JsonData = jsonobj.getString("dataNotificacao");
                                JsonAssunto = jsonobj.getString("assunto");
                                JsonVisualizado = jsonobj.getString("visualizado");
                                JsonTexto = jsonobj.getString("texto");

                                itens.add(new ItemListaNotificacao(JsonData, JsonAssunto,JsonTexto));
                                //ItemListView item[i] = new ItemListView(JsonData, JsonAssunto);
                            }
                            adapterListView = new AdapterListNotificacao(getApplicationContext(), itens);

                            //Define o Adapter
                            ListNotificacao.setAdapter(adapterListView);
                            // Habilitar novamente a notificacao
                            // Notifica o Spinner de que houve mudanca no modelo
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                        System.out.println("Deu ERROR PQP");
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        msgerro();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
        );

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req,
                tag_json_arry);

    }
```

Comment: A mensagem de retorno gerada no Web service (servidor) está correta? Ou somente na recepção (cliente) dos dados isso ocorre?

Comment: A do WebService to retornando como Json e está vindo Errada ja.

Comment: Se mensagem vem do banco de dados é provável, então, que seja lá, o padrão de caracteres, do banco de dados, pode estar incompatível com o padrão dos dados gravados.

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver a usar o método EntityUtils.toString() então pode definir a codificação da mensagem. ex:

```
string data = EntityUtils.toString(<resposta do web service>,HTTP.UTF_8);
```

sendo que  é do tipo HttpEntity

De qualquer modo é melhor meter aqui as partes do código que sejam relevantes.